# Why my info.plist is not a working iphone info.plist

Tags: iphone, info.plist

My first problem is  that i don't want my apps stay in background once i'have quit it with home button.
So i have added 'UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend' key in my info.plist file with boolean type.
The value 'UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend' is not recognized by Xcode, and my app continue to stay in background ...

Source of my problem is that i have deleted reference of Group 'Resources' containing  info.plist. Instead ,i have created a 'real' directory 'resources' with my info.plist (and with other resources as images, ...) and added it to my project. And now all options specific for iPhone are not recognized by Xcode and worth not used on my apps.
In property of my project i have setted 'Info.plist file' key  to my info.plist but it don't work ...
I have rebuild code sense index, but it don't work ...

What i have forget to do ?
Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to direct your project to the location of Info.plist. If you've put it in a 'real' directory named 'Resources', do the following: hit project -> edit active target; find the setting named 'Info.plist File' and change its value to 'Resources/Info.plist'. Clean and rebuild your project, and it should work properly.

Also, make sure that your Info.plist file is **not** being built in your current target. Xcode will give you a compiler warning in this scenario.

Comment: Thx for this. But iphone property as 'UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend' (key for value 'Application does not run in background') are not recognized ...

Comment: Are you building for iOS 4? Is the info.plist value for 'UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend' a boolean value? That is, not 'TRUE' or 'FALSE', but a checkbox you can tick or untick. It must be a checkbox or it is not a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is converting my info.plist file to xml.  I created a new blank project just to see the info.plist file and saw that it was in xml, whereas my older project did not have info.plist in xml format.  So, I used the new info.plist xml format to rewrite my info.plist file.